# Find N first elements which pass given condition: sums up to given number

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have list of `Pocket` instances

```
List<Pocket> pockets;
```

where `Pocket` class looks like below:

```
public class Pocket {
    String name;
    Double amount;
}
```

Example list of pockets:

```
[
    {"pocket1", 280},
    {"pocket2", 320},
    {"pocket3", 100},
    {"pocket4", 125},
    {"pocket5", 150},
    {"pocket6", 175}
]
```

I need to find `n` first pockets which together could give `N` (for example 650) from given list of pockets. In case last pocket has `amount` bigger than it is needed, this pocket should be splitted on two pockets and result list should contain only one part which together with previous `n - 1` pockets gives `N`.

For example, I need list of pockets in order like in source list which gives together amount `650`. Notice that `3-rd` pocket was splitted and only half of `amount` was returned in last pocket:

```
[
    {"pocket1", 280},
    {"pocket2", 320},
    {"pocket3", 50}
]
```

How to implement it with `Java Streams`?

Comment: Have you already done it without streams?

Comment: I think you mean a list of pockets with amount summing to 650, and what have you tried?

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. Do you want to : 1) sum until the amount exceed 650 ? 2) Sum the 650 first pockets ? 3) Find a combination of pockets which sum is 650 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap` and `Stream` to do that. See below example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Lambda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pocket> pockets = Arrays.asList(
            new Pocket("pocket1", 280D),
            new Pocket("pocket2", 320D),
            new Pocket("pocket3", 100D),
            new Pocket("pocket4", 50D));

        System.out.println("Filtered");
        pockets.stream()
            .flatMap(new SplitFunction(651))
            .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("Original");
        pockets.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}


class SplitFunction implements Function<Pocket, Stream<Pocket>> {

private double max;

public SplitFunction(double max) {
    this.max = max;
}

@Override
public Stream<Pocket> apply(Pocket pocket) {
    if (Double.compare(max, pocket.amount) >= 0) {
        max -= pocket.amount;
        return Stream.of(pocket);
    } else if (Double.compare(max, 0.0) > 0) {
        Pocket lastPocket = new Pocket(pocket.name, max);
        max = 0;

        return Stream.of(lastPocket);
    }
    return Stream.empty();
}
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Filtered
Pocket{name='pocket1', amount=280.0}
Pocket{name='pocket2', amount=320.0}
Pocket{name='pocket3', amount=51.0}
Original
Pocket{name='pocket1', amount=280.0}
Pocket{name='pocket2', amount=320.0}
Pocket{name='pocket3', amount=100.0}
Pocket{name='pocket4', amount=50.0}
```

Comment: Example working well but still unclear for me, @Michał Ziober could you please provide proof where I can investigate solution?

Comment: @user3219730, could you please specify what do you mean by "proof". Do you mean that I should explain algorithm why it works?

Comment: by proof, I mean a link to the book, article or example with some description. An algorithm is fully understood for me, I just want to understand why here
`pockets.stream().flatMap(new SplitFunction(651))`
was created one instance of SplitFunction instead of a new instance for each element in the stream.

Comment: @Kuinji43, This is what documentation says for `mapper` param: "mapper – a non-interfering, stateless function to apply to each element which produces a stream of new values". This is how this method was implemented. Of course our implementation is not `stateless` because we keep `amount`. But for not `stream()` it should work OK. Some problems will occur when you start using `parallelStream()` so I do not recommend that. See [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)